# Laravel Api Documentation Genarator

Tags: laravel, api

I've installed the `composer require mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator` according to what the documentation says.
Also published the config file
Now when I run the `php artisan apidoc:generate` command
I got the following error, have searched google but din't find anything relevant,
`Argument 1 passed to Mpociot\ApiDoc\Tools\DocumentationConfig::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\WaheedSindhani\Projects\petApp\vendor\mpociot\laravel-apidoc-generator \src\Commands\GenerateDocumentation.php on line 61`

Comment: Did you create an issue on github for that particular package?

Answer (score 3):

it is a config cache problem
`php artisan config:clear` has solved the problem'

Comment: Great! That package isn't maintained anymore, though. You should use this: https://github.com/knuckleswtf/scribe